# Trying to get cron.php working in Cpanel for Magento

Tags: cron, cpanel, cron-task

I have been using this

`/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/sub.domain.com/cron.php` as my command

for the cron job, but I dont get anything. No customer emails, no errors, nothing. When I use

`php /home/username/public_html/sub.domain.com/cron.php`

I get the error (Or not error)

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.37
Content-type: text/html
```

and if I use

```
/home/username/public_html/sub.domain.com/cron.php
```

I get the overly long error

```
/home/username/public_html/sub.domain.com/cron.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/home/username/public_html/sub.domain.com/cron.php: line 2: /bin: is a directory
/home/username/public_html/sub.domain.com/cron.php: line 3: access-logs: command not found
/home/username/public_html/sub.domain.com/cron.php: line 4: access-logs: command not found
/home/username/public_html/sub.domain.com/cron.php: line 5: access-logs: command not found
/home/username/public_html/sub.domain.com/cron.php: line 6: access-logs: command not found
/home/username/public_html/sub.domain.com/cron.php: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/username/public_html/sub.domain.com/cron.php: line 7: ` * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)'
```

Any idea what im doing wrong here?

FYI: The permissions of the cron.php file is 744.
(For search results)
This is for a Magento 1.9 install that is not sending emails. Check below for the fixes.

Comment: So, anyone able to help?

Comment: If you execute the command directly, it will be executed by `/bin/sh` unless you have `#!/usr/bin/php` as the first line; that's why you're getting those verbose error messages. It looks like those two lines are simply the output produced by your script. What output were you expecting, and what's in `cron.php`? Is `/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/sub.domain.com/cron.php` a line in your crontab, or is it a command you're running from a shell prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few tries, this worked for me.

```
*   *   *   *   *   php /home/sturdi6/public_html/cron.php > /dev/null
```

However the underlying issue I was having (sending confirmation emails) ended up being me needing a SMTP plugin and configuring it to use a webmail address I made in cpanel

[SMTP Pro Email - Free Custom SMTP Email](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html)

That in addition to installing a scheduler to make sure all the cron jobs were managed, had them sending out immediately as it should of all along lol

[AOE Scheduler](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html)

Also some neat things to make note of. The [Magento Cleanup Tool](http://realtuts.com/how-to-clear-magento-internal-server-error-after-installation/) (mass repairs permissions on the folders structure) and the "[Magento not sending Emails](http://www.hummingbirduk.com/magento-not-sending-emails/)?" site, which had some useful scripts for making sure your mail is enabled and sending to begin with.